# Getting ambiguous error for specflow test

Tags: specflow

Getting ambiguous error for specflow test.
I realized the solution is that two stepdefinitions file share the same identical wording of the Given tag so I had to make it unique and then it solved the error.
Tested it by right clicking the test feature file to go to the specflow step definitions.
Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the solution is that two stepdefinitions file share the same identical wording of the Given tag so I had to make it unique and then it solved the error. Tested it by right clicking the test feature file to go to the specflow step definitions. Hope this helps others.